# How to change android application resource id value

Tags: android, aapt

Generally, AAPT is packaging an application with fixed resource id, and the id value is starting with "0x7f".

I want to replace this integer value with other value, like "0x6f" or something.

I found the code line to handle this, and modified the aapt code. (path : `/frameworks/base/tools/aapt/`)

But, when building an application, I got the build error message like:

> /apps/myapps/AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@drawable/ic_launcher_app')."\

Is there any way to solve this build error ?

Comment: Umm, why are you doing this?  I'm unable to think of a good reason.

Comment: Every now and then, some fresh user tries to change the resource values. Nobody knows why, but they do. I think in the beginning I also tried to, but soon I understood that R.Java must **never** be touched.

Comment: In my project, there is a case that I have to know which application has the right resources of the res id.

Comment: In my project, there is a case that I have to know which application has the right resources of the res id. When getting the resource id through getString method's parameter, I just wanna know where I have to find the right resources, from my context or from other context which created by context.createApplicationContext(otherPackageName) API.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [Android resources dev page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html) you should never modify the R file yourself as it is generated automatically

> Caution: You should never modify the R.java file by hand—it is generated by the aapt tool when your project is compiled. Any changes are overridden next time you compile.

Answer (score 0):

That means  ic_launcher_app image not in your drawable folder.  And also if you change image format manually like .jpg to save as .Png without using any software that AAPT(while compile resources into binary assets) issue will occur.so use proper image formats.